# Changing extent on a raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I rasterized a shape. The resulting raster (lets call it raster 1) has a different extent.

I made a virtual raster with the original polygon and I tried to multiply the virtual raster  with raster 1 selecting the virtual raster's extent using raster calc... but I can't get the raster 1 to change the extent... does anyone know how to fix that?

In the picture, the blue part shows the difference between the original vector and the resulting raster.
[image: In the picture, the blue part shows the difference between the original vector and the resulting raster]

Comment: Does the image not cover all of the vector? You used GDAL_Rasterize to create the raster? Did the raster exist prior to this operation? According to the docs, if you use -te  xmin ymin xmax ymax with -tr CellX CellY in georeferenced coordinates it should create a raster to fit that. It looks like the rasterize function has covered just the extent of the features to be rasterized.